# Expected number of days to reduce to non positive integer

Tags: probability

I have three integers 3,4 and 5 on the blackboard.  Each day, I choose one of the integers uniformly at random and decrease it by 1.  Find the expected number of days before which there is no positive number on the blackboard.

If someone can help me, that will be great?

Comment: You have to tell us how you choose which number to decrement. Do you just choose each one with probability $\frac12$?

Comment: The intergers are chosen randomly with equal probability, you are right

Comment: Please edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: A problem with a very similar motif can be found in this video: [Spin Until You Lose - Probability Riddle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lU-hIq2STHk)

Comment: I don't really understand how it is the corollary question. Could you explain? Wouldn't the expected number of draws before both balls are drawn be infinity?  The analogy I can think of is: there are three urns with inf. many balls arranged in a stack (so each time you take the ball - it is from the top of the stack), and the top 3, 4 and 5 balls of the respective urns are colored. Find the expected number of draws until all the colored balls are out.

Comment: You are right, so when the urn with 3 balls get picked  (all three), you are going to pick uncolored balls everytime that urn is selected ( many times) before the other urns get rid of their colored balls.  So I am looking for a reverse hypergeometric distribution (kind of) as the probability of picking colored balls also reduce everytime it is drawn and thrown out

Comment: Do you know how to solve the problem that you stated, that is the re formulation of the original problem

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I would love to. I've written a program to find the average of the number of draws of 10 million simulations and got around 17.841 (+- 0.004) draws.

Comment: I dont think there is closed form solution for this. Simlations are the way to go. This problem is a contest problem from HMMT ( I shortened to get some idea in here)

Comment: I am in the middle of something and will let you know when I have time

Comment: Thanks. Just found it myself though. It is in [this document](https://mathwo.github.io/assets/files/HMMT-1998-2020-problems.pdf), February 10, 2018 — GUTS ROUND number 34.

Comment: Set up a 4x5x6 array, where $A_{ijk}$ will be the expected time if you start with numbers $i-1,j-1$ and $k-1$.  Understood, a number equals zero includes that number being negative.  Now, by induction on $i+j+k$, calculate $A_{ijk}$ until you have $A_{456}$ which is your answer.

Comment: It comes to 3329563/729/256 = 17.8410226

Comment: The original problem, starting with numbers 1-10, my program says 120.75280458, but the denominator would have powers of 10! in it